# How to implement Actionable Push Notifications for iOS in React Native?

Tags: ios, swift, react-native, push-notification

We are kind of stuck at implementing actionable push notifications for **iOS** in **react native** for a project. We are currently using this [React Native library for push notifications](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-push-notification).In their docs, they sayy  [to use this other library](https://github.com/holmesal/react-native-ios-notification-actions) to create the actions but it is pretty old and it's not currently working for React Native 0.59 and neither for Xcode 10.3.

Is there any good tutorial or guide that you know about that can help out?

I have seen in the [PushNotificationIOS](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/pushnotificationios) docs that there is a **category** property which triggers natively the push notification with the corresponding actions, I know that we must implement that in Xcode, but I just can't find anywhere the appropriate implementation. Also, how can we pass the action selection handler to react native so we can trigger the appropriate actions in the component?

I attach the following image so that it is clear what the actions in the notification look like. Thanks a lot for the help!

[Actionable Push Notifications in iOS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NMJxJ.jpg)